# SP 2013 Blog Page Shows List when clicking on Blog Post

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I have been asked to fix a SP2013 Blog site created by my boss. The issue is that when you click on the title of a specific blog post from list view, it simply shows the list again on load. The expected action is to view the details of the item selected.

I have not tried to delete the blog because it's actively used with about 125 items. Is there a way to edit the part specifically so that when clicking the item you see just that item?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Posts list view page(/Lists/Posts/AllPosts.aspx) in blog site, and Modify the View to check if you use the Title (linked to item with edit menu) field in list view.

[image]

And back to the list view page, click this link Title column again to check it it works.

And you can check if some custom code in this list view page.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. The same issue is happening after following your steps. The list looks like a normal list, but will not link to detail.